# cassandra and nodetool not able to connect

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to connect to cqlsh but i am getting this error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

When i try nodetool status it gives me error

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

In my cassandra.yaml there is start_rpc: true. My rpc address is set to rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

i have check service by ervice --status-all and cassandra is running.

I have also tried and search for all possible solutions, but nothing helped.

Please help me as i am new to cassandra development.

Comment: What version of Cassandra you are using and what is your listen address configured

Comment: i am using cassandra 3.2 and listen address is set to blank. i am working on server where other people can connect to cassandra but i cant

Comment: "i am working on server where other people can connect to cassandra but i cant" -> It seems you are trying to connect on your local address(127.0.0.1) cassandra. Find servers ip and port and mention it as parameter when connecting.

Comment: now when i run cqlsh i can connect but when i run code from java it gives me pool closed error

Comment: i have checked nodetool status and its down for my port..how can i bring it up